# Migrate Drupal locator content to Wordpress site

Tags: migrations

I use the migrate module to populate locator data to other Drupal sites. We have a main site that allows members to update their locations. Each location can also be flagged so that if its checked as an "A" location, when Cron runs it populates on the "A" site and the same for the "B" site. This keeps the content updated on the other sites when any changes are made and allows us to only have to update on one site. All the sites are running on Drupal 7.

Now if we added a WordPress site and wanted to route the "A" locations content to that site instead, can this be done the same way?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure this is a Drupal question? IMO it is rather about WP ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

also saw your email...

The migrate module is very Drupal-centric. It runs on a Drupal site, and the primary (99.99%) use-case is to pull data into that Drupal site - all destination plugins I know of write to the local Drupal database. That being said, it would be entirely possible to write a destination plugin that pushed to an external destination - like, say, a WordPress database or a web service for creating content.

Personally, my only experience with WordPress is in importing content from WordPress exports (XML files) into Drupal, so I don't know how challenging pushing content to WordPress would be.